# Using ElementTree's iterfind for deep XML parsing

Tags: python, xml-parsing, lxml, elementtree

I am trying to parse all the IPv6 *address* elements using iterfind.  I thought my match string is correct, but I am not seeing any results.  I am not familiar with parsing deep XML files, so I am starting to question is this method the best approach?

```
import requests 
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

r = requests.get('https://support.content.office.net/en-us/static/O365IPAddresses.xml')

root = ET.fromstring(r.text)

for node in root.iterfind(".//products/product/[@name='o365']/addresslist/[@type='IPv6']"):
    data = []
    for d in node.getchildren():
        if d.text:
            data.append(d.text)
    print ' '.join(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a step back and make sure your xpath expression is correct.  Start with:

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://support.content.office.net/en-us/static/O365IPAddresses.xml')
>>> root = ET.fromstring(r.text)
```

If you search for the beginning of your xpath expression, `.//products`, what do you get?

```
>>> root.findall('.//products/product')
[]
```

You get an empty list, which means there's a problem with your expression.  That's because the root of your tree is the `products` element:

```
>>> root
<Element 'products' at 0x7f16be5a9450>
```

So the first level of the hiearchy will be `product`:

```
>>> root.findall('product')
[<Element 'product' at 0x7f16be5a9490>, <Element 'product' at 0x7f16be0e4190>, ...]
```

If you substitute that back into your full expression, we get:

```
>>> root.findall("product/[@name='o365']/addresslist/[@type='IPv6']")
[<Element 'addresslist' at 0x7f16be5a94d0>]
```

That seems much better.

Using that expression in your example code produces output that seems reasonable.